Unable to Access Spotify API Dashboard | Spotify Web API

img - error
img - inspector panel

inspector panel

"Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)."

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://gae2-spclient.spotify.com/gabo-receiver-service/public/v3/events. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)."


while access "https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard" it throws this error message
I have tried all browser (chrome, brave, edge). same for all
in mobile can able to access but in laptop not able to access
how to resolve?

Did you try logout/login at https://open.spotify.com/? It will clear your session.

resolved - after set time and time zone automatically.
Thanks
Bench Vue

Resolved.
after set time and time zone automatically.
solution

Because the imgur link could expire (or the service could disappear), I recommend you write the steps for the Windows Settings that you performed so other users who are beginners will know how to fix it if they encounter this issue.

oh okay!, I have face this issue before "not synchronize with my clock ". after sync with my clock the problem solved for me. i have used this you tube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESIBWdJHHxg
